# Angular : how remove dropped item in drag and drop angular/cdk

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, drag-and-drop

I develop some drag-and-drop UI using angular/CDK, Now I want to remove the dropped items from the droplist. How to remove the items from dropList

Typescript Code :

```
  drop(event: any) {
    console.log(event.container.data);

    console.log('drop');
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      console.log('move');
      moveItemInArray(
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
    } else {
      console.log('trans');
      copyArrayItem(
        event.previousContainer.data,
        event.container.data,
        event.previousIndex,
        event.currentIndex
      );
      console.log('trans2', this.done);
    }
  }
```

Please check the below stackblitz for ref.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msacoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

I'm Expecting below behaviour

[image]

Comment: Link doesn't work

Comment: try this one, Please 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-msacoy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @MarkoMarinkovic Please check it now or see previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### UPDATE

The new question **How to delete the Button** is very easy.

First: in HTML part you know the item (or its id) from the `ngFor` loop. Set set this to the `click` event to the button.

```
<span class="badge bg-primary me-2"
      *ngFor="let it of item.items">
      {{ it.ruleName }}

      <button (click)="deleteMe($event, it)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">X</button>
</span>
```

So, then you have a `done` property which is an `array`. So loop the array and search in it's `items[]` for your id. Like this:

```
deleteMe(event: any, data: any) {
    console.log(data)
    for (let _done of this.done) {
      const findOne = _done.items.findIndex(f => f.ruleId === data.ruleId)
      if (findOne > -1) {
        _done.items.splice(findOne, 1)
        break;
      }
    }
  }
```

An all works as well!

#### ----------------

It's simple. Instead of `copyArrayItem()` use the cdkDrags `transferArrayItem()` method. And the transfer will work as well.

**Replace this one...**

```
...
copyArrayItem(
  event.previousContainer.data,
  event.container.data,
  event.previousIndex,
  event.currentIndex
);
...
```

**...to this:**

```
...
transferArrayItem(
   event.previousContainer.data,
   event.container.data,
   event.previousIndex,
   event.currentIndex,
);
...
```

Comment: I'm expecting left side list should be stay, after drag and drop. if we use transferArrayItem it will moved, i think.

Comment: Then your Stackblitz sample works correctly. The `copyArrayItem` do what you want, doesn't it?

Comment: I need to delete the items from the dropped container(Right side).

Comment: Please look at the edited question.

Comment: My answer is updated, too

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It's working.